# JavaScript - Showing array elements inside HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript page (function.js) that is included in my game.php and within functions.js is defined an array. Like this:

```
var palavra=[];
    function fun(){
        var input=document.getElementById("palavra").value;
        var letra1=input.charAt(0);
        var letra2=input.charAt(1);
        var letra3=input.charAt(2);
        var letra4=input.charAt(3);
        var letra5=input.charAt(4);
        letra1=palavra[0];
        letra2=palavra[1];
        letra3=palavra[2];
        letra4=palavra[3];
        letra5=palavra[4];
    }
```

This function is triggered by an onclick event in the game.php page:

```
<input id="palavra" type="text" name="palavra" maxlength="5">
        <button onclick="fun()" id="btn"> Enviar</button>
```

I want each index of the array to show in the middle of html tag like show bellow (also in the game.php)

```
    <span class="letra"><script> palavra[0]</script></span>
    <span class="letra"><script> palavra[1]</script></span>
    <span class="letra"><script> palavra[2]</script></span>
    <span class="letra"><script> palavra[3]</script></span>
    <span class="letra"><script> palavra[4]</script></span>
```

However, when I click on the button nothing happens and I have the following errors:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: palavra is not defined at game.php

Uncaught ReferenceError: fun is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (game.php)
```

I don't understand why this is happening, can someone tell me where the problem is.

Comment: These reference errors means that your variables are not accessible when `onclick` is executed. It could mean that path to source file is invalid or that there is a problem with async loading (*if* you are loading the script asynchronously).

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do, however, from what I understand, you can achieve what you want to achieve by using a `for-in` loop to get every character in your input. Then instead of using HTML to input each letter, you use javascript by doing `document.body.innerHTML` to append each letter/character to your document.

See working example below:

```js
function fun() {
  var input = document.getElementById("palavra").value;

  for (i in input) {
    document.body.innerHTML += '<br /><span class="letra">' + input[i] + '</span>';
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="palavra" type="text" name="palavra" maxlength="5" />
<button onclick="fun()" id="btn"> Enviar</button>

<!-- This will be generated using javascript-->
<!--span class="letra"><script> palavra[0]</script></span>
<span class="letra"><script> palavra[1]</script></span>
<span class="letra"><script> palavra[2]</script></span>
<span class="letra"><script> palavra[3]</script></span>
<span class="letra"><script> palavra[4]</script></span-->
```